# Python 2 to 3 conversion decode hex

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

I have a question about a script. The code blow is a function wich was developed for Python 2.x but i can not convert it to Python 3 code.
I have limited know-how in Python, but i want to learn
The main problem is `.decode('hex')`  i already tried  `codecs.decode` and `codecs.getdecoder( 'hex_codec')`  Nothing worked at this moment

The request string is build from several parts. The first part is a
fixed 4 char string; the second part is the reversed hex notation of
the s/n twice; then again a fixed string of two chars; a checksum of
the double s/n with an offset; and finally a fixed ending char.

```
'''
responseString = '\x68\x02\x40\x30';

doublehex = hex(ser)[2:]*2
hexlist = [ doublehex[i:i+2].decode('hex') for i in 
    reversed(range(0, len(doublehex), 2))]

cs_count = 115 + sum([ ord(c) for c in hexlist])
cs = hex(cs_count)[-2:].decode('hex')
responseString += ''.join(hexlist) + '\x01\x00'+cs+'\x16'
return responseString
```

Comment: Could you please fix your code formatting?